# Duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    U.nick AS author_nick,
    P.id AS post_id,
    P.name AS post_name,
    P.author AS post_author_id,
    P.date AS post_date,
    U2.nick AS post_author
FROM 
    zero_topics T
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_posts P
ON 
    T.id = P.topic_id
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U
ON 
    T.author = U.uuid
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U2
ON 
    P.author = U2.uuid
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN P.date is null THEN T.date
    ELSE P.date 
END DESC
```

Output:

[image: output]

Topics:

[image: topics]

Posts:

[image: posts]

Question: Why i have duplicated topic id 22? i have in mysql two topics (id 22 and 23) and two posts(id 24 and 25). I want to see topic with last post only.

Comment: How can we know without understanding the data on your tables and how you should join them?

Comment: How is the query supposed to know that you only want the most recent post?  Your query says to get all matches.  You need additional logic to choose only the most recent one.

Comment: Well, there you have it, the join condition between your tables is `T.id = P.topic_id` and both posts have `topic_id = 22`, ergo, you get 2 rows as a result

Comment: I selected all topics(but 22 is doubled), then last post and order. What logic do i need here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a join produces multiple results and you want only at most one result, you have to rewrite the join and/or filtering criteria to provide that result. If you want only the latest result of all the results, it's doable and reasonably easy once you use it a few times.

```
select  a.Data, b.Data
from    Table1 a
left join Table2 b
    on  b.JoinValue = a.JoinValue
    and b.DateField =(
        select Max( DateField )
        from   Table2
        where  JoinValue = b.JoinValue );
```

The correlated subquery pulls out the *one date* that is the highest (most recent) value of all the joinable candidates. That then becomes the row that takes part in the join -- or, of course, nothing if there are no candidates at all. This is a pattern I use quite a lot.